# Get the Url status through rest API into apex region

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an link url "http://ucsmv4007.us.oracle.com:7002/MosClientsDataSync/rest/status/bridge" will return status as either up or down.

I need to show the status in Apex Application Region, how can i perform this through API call, to get the url status into region?

Thanks!
Abinnaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is show the remote page in your APEX page, you can create a region that contains an `iframe`. Create a static region with the following content:

```
<iframe src="http://ucsmv4007.us.oracle.com:7002/MosClientsDataSync/rest/status/bridge">
</iframe>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

If you need to do some processing or conditions based on the result of the data that you get back from the URL, however, you'll need to load it on the server instead, e.g. using `UTL_HTTP`.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-94D1CFA6-460D-4C97-B68A-4AA0EF0E4BC1

```
DECLARE
  url   varchar2(2000) := 'http://ucsmv4007.us.oracle.com:7002/MosClientsDataSync/rest/status/bridge';
  req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  value varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url);
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp, value, TRUE);
    -- do something with value
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

Comment: I am getting the below error...  ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Comment: The ACL is the database's firewall. You can open it by creating an ACL that allows your schema to connect to that endpoint. More info here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1